# Convert DataAccess list to ObjectModel list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I'm working on a multi-layered architecture project using C#.
One of the methods I have to do in each class would be to convert a list of DAL objects to list of OM objects, like in the following example:

```
private List<OM.Employee> DAL_To_OM(List<DAL.Employee> list)
{
    List<OM.Employee> retList = list.ConvertAll(e => new OM.Employee
    {
        Name = e.Name,
        Age = e.Age
    });

    return retList;
}
```

My question here, is there any way to write a generic function that achieves this in a generic way, like converting List to List where both T1 and T2 have same properties?

Comment: Did you look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)  library ?

Comment: I just did. It's a cool solution, preserve a lot of coding. I'll look if I can use it in a generic way (without specifying the source and destination type). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection for this (but keep in mind that reflection is slow, depending on your classes and size of lists it may be too slow):

```
public class Converter<T1,T2>
{
    public static List<T1> Convert(List<T2> t2List)
    {
        List<T1> t1List = t2List.ConvertAll<T1>(Convert);
        return t1List;
    }

    public static T1 Convert(T2 t2)
    {
        T1 t1 = Activator.CreateInstance<T1>();

        List<PropertyInfo> t1PropertyInfos = new List<PropertyInfo>(typeof(T1).GetProperties());
        List<PropertyInfo>  t2PropertyInfos = new List<PropertyInfo>(typeof(T2).GetProperties());
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t1PropertyInfos)
        {
           PropertyInfo data = t2PropertyInfos.Find(p => p.Name.Equals(pi.Name));
           if (data != null)
           {
              pi.SetValue(t1, data.GetValue(t2, new object[0]), new object[0]);
           }
       }

       return t1;
   }
```

}

Comment: I'll go with AutoMapper in my project, since I'll be using a lot the conversion method so it may affect the performance as you said. But your answer is what I was looking for when I asked my question. Thank you.